# REGEX possible to return true if a string is found between script tags?

Tags: php

I am cURLing a page and want to check if this string is found anywhere on the page between javascript tags (using php):

```
';()//
```

But there could be other code between like:

```
<script>
..stuff
';()//
.. more stuff
</script>
```

Can anyone post an example?

Comment: Nothing, its an urgent fix I don't know regex well.

Comment: You just want to know if the string exists? Don't need to know what code is around it?

Comment: yeah just if the string is there, anywhere between script tags (so not return true if found before or after script tags)

Comment: @user1166981: This last comment clarified a lot. You should edit your post and add that information.

Answer (score 1):

This kinda do the job:

```
echo preg_match("#script.*';\(\)\/\/.*\/script#im", str_replace("\n", "", $html), $matches);
```

It returns 1 if a match was found, 0 if none.